# skipping a file in cobol based on a variable

Tags: cobol

i have a large cobol source code file that reads one file, checks for id's in a specific record, processes, then repeats till there are no more files.  I have a few records that contain ids that I do not want to process.  I'd like read the file, read the record, if the record variable equals a certain string, i'd like to move to the next file and do nothing with this file.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried ???, you could read the "skip id's" from a file into a table and do a search on the table to check wether to process or not. Alternatively if the file is in key sequence you could use a "Merge process". The merge would take

Comment: these are edi files (purchase orders).  the files come in and the first record is looked at and grabs the senders id and places it in a variable.

Comment: the program executes different processes based on that variable

Comment: what id like to do is skip all process if the variable reads , in this case, walmart.

Comment: Presumably your existing processing gets to EOF, closes, possibly does some stuff, then starts with the next one. Set a flag to say "data not needed" and treat that like end-of-file. That's a logical outline, not a suggestion of how to code it :-)

Comment: i'll try that,,thanks